# Designing scaling services with high available load-balancing

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, devops, marathon

When running self-healing, scalable stateless services in frameworks such as [marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/), the "affirmed" pattern is to have a tool for service discovery (e.g., [bamboo](https://github.com/QubitProducts/bamboo)) that feeds a load-balancer (e.g., [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)), preferrably with some automatic configuration, so that users can be proxied to services when hitting the load-balancer.

I don't seem to find much material about how to make the load-balancer itself highly available.

If the host that runs the load-balancer dies, I would like the services to still be accessed on the same URIs without downtimes.

What I desire can be achieved with Pacemaker/Corosync, but the fact that this specific point is often omitted in the various tutorials and blog posts, makes me think that maybe there is a simpler pattern or that I am overlooking the problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Running HaProxy at scale on Marathon with common source of config (mounted) might help ? I am thinking on lines of offloading that requirement on Marathon itself #RandomThought

Comment: @akskap, thanks for the comment! But even in that case, say that you are pointing to `theapp.slave-ip`, which HaProxy redirects to an instance of `theapp`, then, if the slave dies, how do you point to a new slave? Maybe some DNS magic? Or probably the only solution is indeed a floating IP managed with pacemaker.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is to run multiple machines with Bamboo/HAProxy on them pulling container locations from the Marathon/Mesos masters. In an AWS/Cloud-du-jour environment, these proxy machines can go behind an ELB (or even in an Autoscaling Group if your automation is good enough) to give you true HA functionality.

Comment: That works, but you have to rely on the Availability of the ELB of the cloud-du-jour provider :). How would you do it on premises? DNS, Pacemaker?

Comment: Yep, some sort of Pacemaker-like setup.